# Help with classes in php

Tags: php, class, object

```
class Controller {

    protected $_controller;
    protected $_action;
    protected $_template;

    public $doNotRenderHeader;
    public $render;

    function __construct($controller, $action) {

        $this->_controller = ucfirst($controller);
        $this->_action = $action;
        $model = ucfirst($controller);/* Conecting the model  class*/
        $this->doNotRenderHeader = 0;
        $this->render = 1;
        $modelName = ucfirst($model).'Model';
        new $modelName;
        $this->_template = new Template($controller,$action);

    }

    function set($name,$value) {
        $this->_template->set($name,$value);
    }


    function __destruct() {
        if ($this->render) {
            $this->_template->render($this->doNotRenderHeader);
        }
    }

}
```

I'm a newbie in working with classes , i don't understand so much , i want to implement and to study to work with classes this example of mvc structure , but i have a problem , with function set I'm saving into array , some information and then to sent inside class template , when i using inside function __construct I'm sending with set() function that have the role to save data into $this_template object, it's working ok , but when i'm creating a new function  in this class or extended class , is not working ...

The question is - how to do , when i create a function in Controller class , to set in array the value that i need , to work with them inside class template :)
 thanks very much for helping ..and sorry for my English

```
class Template {
    protected $variables = array();


function set($name,$value) {
    $this->variables[$name] = $value;
}


    function render(){
        extract($this->variables); print_r($this->variables);
    }
}
```

I need with function set() from Class Controller to export data inside class Template  , and why when i creating a function inside Class Controller
ex :

```
function functionName() {
   $data=array('a','b');
   $this->set('data',$data);
}
```

and inside `class Template` , i putting `print_r($this->variables);` , and the array is empty

Comment: What ist your question? I do not understand.

Comment: Take a look az Zend Framework to understand MVC in PHP

Comment: I don't have so much time , i'm working at one project .. and at this time i'm studying the mvc structure and to work with classes

Comment: You've asked something very vague in poor english.  It will help if you post the code you're trying to get to work, what you're trying to do, and why it doesn't work.  Then we'll have a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: ok , I'll try to write more explicit

Answer (score 0):

```
__construct($controller, $action) {

        $this->_controller = ucfirst($controller);
...}
```

What exactly is the type of variable $controller?  is is a string, perhaps?  and should it be called "controller_name"?

```
$model = ucfirst($controller);/* Conecting the model  class*/
...
$modelName = ucfirst($model).'Model';
```

Isn't the ucfirst redundant on the second line?

```
new $modelName;
```

should be

```
$this->somevariable = new Someclass($modelName);
```

anyway, you have to go back to the drawing board and clean this up.
Perhaps this is too complex of an exercise for your first project using classes.